# How to use ListBuffer in scala?

Tags: scala

I have a situation where I am passing a single element list to a method. Within this method, the single element in the list is incremented by one. So that after method call, the list first element is modified ( incremented by one).

Code is like this:

```
val ct = List(5)

someMethod(ct)

println (ct(0))

// should print 6
```

......

```
//within somethod, I incrment the element like:
def someMethod(ct: List[Int}) {
    ct(0) = ct(0) + 1
}
```

Of course above code does not work in Scala. I looked at [ListBuffer](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.8.1/scala/collection/mutable/ListBuffer.html) but I find the scala doc hard to follow. Scala doc is divided into 2 groups: Type Members and Value Members. In type member there is class WithFiler and value members has many methods. How can I use WithFiler ( probably not directly related to this question but I want to understand how to make use of scala doc).

ListBuffer seems to be the right solution for this problem if I want to have very high performance (the someMethod is called millions of times) ( correct me if I am wrong).

So how to solve above problem if ListBuffer is the right type of list and if not what is the solution?

Comment: That's two different questions, really -- one related to using `ListBuffer`, and the other related to understanding Scaladoc's Type Members and Value Members. Please ask the latter question separately.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In scala, the expression:

```
ct(0) = ct(0) + 1
```

is rewritten as:

```
ct.update( 0, ct.apply(0) + 1 )
```

Method `update` is not defined for supertype `List` because lists can be immutable. However, that's the type of the function argument.

So you must use only ListBuffers (or a mutable supertype):

```
def someMethod(ct: ListBuffer[Int]) {
  ct(0) = ct(0) + 1
}

scala> val lst = ListBuffer( 5 )
  lst: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Int] = ListBuffer(5)
scala> someMethod( lst )
scala> lst
  res2: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Int] = ListBuffer(6)
```

By the way, if you need to access elements by indices, use instead an `ArrayBuffer`. It should work as java `ArrayList`.

Finally, If you don't need to think about `WithFilter` stuff. Just use the `filter` method.

Answer (score 5):

If performance is a main goal and maximal size of collection is known, you can use Array which maps directly to java array.

Answer (score 5):

This has the smell of a premature micro-optimisation about it.

Although there are valid reasons for using mutability (including optimisation), you haven't stated why you believe your usage is valid, or the bigger problem that you're trying to solve.  In particular, immutable Lists are *very* efficient when taking the tail and prepending a new head - 100% of the non-head elements will be shared between the original and new List.

As presented, the cleanest solution for your requirements is to forget about `ListBuffer`, stick with an immutable `List` and implement `someMethod` without recourse to side-effects.

```
def someMethod(xs: List[Int]) = xs match {
  case h :: t => (h+1) :: t
  case Nil => Nil
}

val ct = List(5)
println (someMethod(ct).headOption getOrElse "empty list")

// should print 6
```

---

On the other hand, if this *is* a performance hotspot, and you can't identify any way to improve performance by changing the algorithm, then you'll want to use an `Array`

Array is the only reified collection type on the JVM.  As such, you can directly work with primitives in an Array and avoid the boxing/unboxing that other collection types have to contend with.

The advantage here has nothing to do with mutability vs. immutability; the performance cost of unboxing/boxing is far higher than the performance cost (if any) of using an immutable List.

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly rewrite the above to use `ListBuffer`, but if all you want is call-by-reference semantics for a single `Int` it's not necessarily the most efficient solution.  `ArrayBuffer` should be a bit better.  You could also do something like this:

```
class IntCell(var x: Int)
def someMethod(ct: IntCell) {
  ct.x += 1
}
```

I usually try to rewrite my code to avoid using mutable collections for this kind of thing.  For example, you could just return the new value:

```
def someMethod(ct: Int) = ct + 1
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use ListBuffer, all you have to do is to replace word "List" in your code for "ListBuffer". However, I would avoid the side-effect function (yours someMethod: Unit) completely like naten suggests.

ListBuffer has "high performance" - however, the main purpose is adding items/modifying the collection. If I get it correctly, you just update the item in one item collection million times - Array is sufficient for that.